# Welcome Our New Overlords

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, science

[image: Welcome Our New Overlords]

Clues: [contextual symbols]
[kg*m/s] [m/s^2]
[male symbol]
What is Toronto?????

Instructions: Who Won Second Place?

_ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ _ S

Comment: Is the Toronto thing a reference to some rather obscure movie or song I don't know? Because I'm guessing it's that due to the "knowledge" tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> Ken Jennings

Reasoning:
The image is of a:

> family tree.  For the parents, on the left we have momentum (kg m / s) and on the right we have acceleration (m / s^2).  When they are married, they become a Watt (kg m^2 / s^3) or (J/s).  The male child of a set of parents is called the son.  A name for that child could be "Watson".

Expanding on the male:

> Watson is the name of a famous IBM computer that played Jeopardy against Ken Jennings and Brad Rutter.

What about Toronto?

> One of the Final Jeopardy questions for Watson was in the category "U.S. Cities", the answer was "Its largest airport is named for a World War II hero; its second largest, for a World War II battle."  Watson incorrectly responded "What is Toronto?????".  A correct responsed would have been "What is Chicago?"

Explaining the title:

> As part of Jennings final response, he had the comment "(I for one welcome our new computer overlords)"

Results:

> Ken Jennings finished in second place in this competition.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have the full story, but I may be on to something..,

> This has something to do with a sport. the males section.
>  first symbols are "mass $\times$ speed" and "acceleration".  Could be racing, could be sking, could be a lot of them.
>  And second palce was won by NETH**E**RLAND**S**.

Now this is were I got lost.

> Toronto is a city in Canada. But in never hosted an Olympic event (summer or winter). But maybe this is not a reference to Olympics and I'm way off. Or maybe I'm supposed get Canada from "Toronto".
>  Anyway... I'm lost... Canada hosted 3 Olympics. Summer 1976, Winter 1988 and 2010.
>  It's not Vancouver because Netherlands only got second place in women 1000m speed skating.
>  in 1988 Netherlands got silver also only in speed skating (looks like they are good at it) twice for men 500 and 5000 meters.
>  in 1976 men's cycling 4000 meters pursuit.  (probably useless fact, but nice to know)

That's all I got for now. Trying to connect everything else.

Comment: Don't want to have open text spoilers and don't have enough for an answer, but rot13: Gur svefg sbezhyn vf zbzraghz, frpbaq nppryrengvba nf lbh'ir fnvq. Gur znyr flzoby vf na nepure, n fubbgvat neebj unf zbzraghz, gura fybjf zvq nve, gura nppryrengrf gbjneqf ynaq. Znlor gur fcbeg lbh'er ybbxvat sbe vf nepurel?

Comment: hahaha., Maybe.... At least I got something right.

Comment: rot13: lbh ner pbeerpg va nffhzvat gung gurfr ner raretl pnyphyngvbaf. Gur flzoby qbrf abg fgnaq sbe na nepure, gubhtu.

Comment: @Tyler, haha, thank you for the puzzle, now I see the accepted answer and that I led Marius deeper into the woods, sorry @Marius!